# Matching two tables in SQL Server 2008 using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables - `CATEGORY` and `ITEM`

- `CATEGORY` table has 2 columns : `Category` and `Group_Name`
- `ITEM` table has few columns, but columns of interest are `Category`, `Group_Name` and `Item_Name`

**Category** table:

```
Category    GroupName
-----------------------
C1          Electronic
C1            Food
C1            FMCB
C2            foo
C2            bar
```

**Item** table:

```
Category    GroupName   ItemName
---------------------------------
C1          Electronic  Phone
C1          Food        Noodles
C1          ALL_GROUPS  Junk
C2          foo         xyz
```

My requirement are:

1. Each record in `ITEM` table group should have exactly one group matching with `group_name` in `GROUP` table
2. Also, say a `Category` has 3 groups, say A,B,C. `ITEM` table has matching entry only for one group A, but as long as another record with group 'ALL_GROUPS' exists, it's OK.

In the example, category 1 in Item table is OK, since it has 'ALL_GROUPS' but for category 2, group 'bar' is missing.

I wrote the below query but the requirements are not completely satisfied:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CATEGORY A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' 
                  FROM ITEM B  
                  WHERE A.Category = B.Category 
                    AND (A.GROUP_NAME = B.GROUP_NAME  
                         OR A.GROUP_NAME = 'ALL_GROUPS')
                 )
```

Any help?

TIA

----- Added 'actual' screenshot of tables and my requirements. The red highlighted rows should actually be reported (selected) by intended query
[image]

Comment: a table called `GROUP`??? are you serious?

Comment: just for an illustration :)

Comment: What do you want the result set to look like?

Comment: Results will be from 'Category' table whose group_name do not have matching entry in Item table. Taking example above, I would like to select C2   bar  since it does not has an entry in ITEM table for that category

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the alias used in the second condition of the `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Category A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' 
                  FROM Item B  
                  WHERE A.Category = B.Category 
                    AND (A.GroupName = B.GroupName   
                         OR B.GroupName = 'ALL_GROUPS'))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84299/2)

Comment: Sorry, it still doesnt help.. I have added a screenshot in my original question.. The highlighted rows should actually be reported